# how to use window.location.hash?

Tags: jquery, hash

I don't really know the concept of hash but based on what I understand, It prevents a page from redirecting to other page when the user hits the F5 key.

I have this jquery function:

```
$('#f1').click(function()
{
    alert(window.location.hash);
    $("#body").load("sample.php");

});
```

HTML:

```
<a href = "#!sample" id = "f1">FUNC 1</a>
<div id = "body">
<!-- OUTPUT HERE -->
</div>
```

It successfully outputting the content of my sample.php, but when I hit the refresh button or F5 in the keyboard it redirected back to the parent page..

I want that when I hit refresh the content of sample.php will remain in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is wrong. The hash is just a anchor that allows the user to jump into a static position into a document.

For much applications the hash is used for saving states which is not anymore needed there are some technics to change the URL without reloading for the same domain. See also the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

The page is just not reloaded if you change the hash, but if the user presses F5 the page will be reloaded.

Comment: so what I must do to prevent the content(sample.php) from disappearing when the user refresh the page? on jquery navigation

Comment: It's not possible to prevent reloading. You could change the page content after the ready or load event and restore the last state.

Comment: so i think I will just go to the native php navigation. I want to implement just like twitter did. when you go to one user profile and hit refresh it will go to the twitter home for a few seconds and go to the profile again

Comment: Yes they do the same. Or try the facebook way and manipulate the url with the linked api above. When the user reloads the site the server can directly generate the right content. By the way that is IMHO better then a JS only page.

Comment: so PHP navigation plus the use of a framework is always better than a pure Ajax/Jquery website? I think Ajax/Jquery functions are only applicable on some matters?

Comment: I personally support the schema of "layers" on the base is a plain HTML, styled by CSS and with dynamic elements generated by JS. But your site should work if JS is disabled and should be even readable if CSS is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you can make sure that the content loads on refresh is by calling the .load() function on document load, i.e.

```
$(function() {
    $("#body").load("sample.php");
)};
```

Unless there is some very strong reason why you are using a click to reload the content in the #body div